# how to move a github issue from my repo to an organization that i administer?

Tags: github

I am trying to move an issue from my private GitHub repo to my Organization repo (also private). Should I just clone the repo and and then `git push` to the new organization? From there it's easy to move issues between repos.

`https://github.com/me/repo-foo/issues/1` 
to
`https://github.com/organization/repo-foo/`

- both repos are private
- the issue contains images files, no code
- this should be easier, i think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move an issue on github to another repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720718/how-do-i-move-an-issue-on-github-to-another-repo)

Comment: Adding the link to the help page in case someone stumbles on this - https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-an-issue-to-another-repository/