# Move issues across orgs to different repos

Tags: github

We constantly separate modules from a large project and move them to new repos in different orgs. I would like to also move the relevant labeled issues to these new repos. I have write access to both repos.

Github provides [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53091647/3599535) functionality to move issues across repos in the same org. But is there a way to move the issues to a different repo in a different org while keeping the comments and authors intact during the move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GitHub issue importer[1] to move issues to repos in a different repo.

1.http://www.iqandreas.com/github-issues-import/configuration/#enterprise